# Transform IF statement into IF NOT statement (Java)

Tags: java, if-statement

How to transform this IF statement to IF NOT statement?

The purpose of the code is to ignore lines starting with "//" and empty lines.

```
if (lineOfText.contains("//") || lineOfText.length() == 0)
continue;
```

**FILE TO BE READ**

```
// this is a comment, any lines that start with //
// (and blank lines) should be ignored


// data is title, itemCode, cost, timesBorrowed, onLoan
item 1, LM002411,3989,781,true
item 2, LM002711,599,0,FALSE
item 3, LM002876,4599,45,TRUE
item 4, LM002468,6395,0,TRUE
item 5, LM002153,4554,0,FALSE
```

Comment: put the boolean expression in parenthesis and invert it with `!` ?

Comment: `if (!(... || ...))`

Comment: Even if you negate the condition it will not work as you want it to.

Comment: Andrew is not as simple as that, I have already tried that way. Joakim, can you tell me how can I do it?

Comment: I think you want to use  lineOfText.startsWith("//").

Comment: @NomadMaker that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!(lineOfText.startsWith("//") || lineOfText.length() == 0)) {
   // statement
}
```

The solution was to use the `!` to indicate `if-not` inside the outer brackets.

Then create inner brackets where the `if-not` conditions go.

The purpose of `.startsWith("//")` is to ensure that the program will only ignore the lines starting with `//`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the Not expression "!". Your statement looks as follows:

```
if(!(lineOfText.contains("//") || lineOfText.trim().length() == 0){
   //Your code here
}else{
   //Your else-part here
}
```

Comment: It does not work. It only shows the lines that I do not want to output. `// this is a comment, any lines that start with //`

Comment: OK, you might want to try `if(s.length() != 0 && !s.trim().startsWith("//")){` than.